# How to replace an element by textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I am making is basically is a user profile that has a text box for description added by the user about himself/herself. Although I have a separate page where the user can edit the profile, but I want to provide a feature that when a user hovers over his description box then he sees an `edit` button.

If the user clicks that button, then he/she can edit the description field there itself, and the backend will be updated using Ajax. The ajax call and the backend processing is simple, but how can I replace the `html` with a `textarea` and `submit` button and again put back the original html using javascript.

Here is what my html look like

```
<div id="personalText" >
    <a href="#" id="editButton"> edit </a>
    <p id="descText">{{profile.desc}}</p>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks `editButton` I want to replace the html inside `personalText` with a `textarea` containing the original text in `descText`, and an `update` button. And when the user edits the text and click update, I will update the backend model and again put the `<a>` tag and the `<p>` tag.

Can anybody help. I seem to know how to do parts of it, but can't figure out how I will replace the original structure on `update` click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating/destroying DOM elements an option would be to have the edit `<textarea/>` hidden.

```
<div id="personalText" >
    <div class="display">
        <a href="#" id="editButton">edit</a>
        <p id="descText">{{profile.desc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="edit" style="display:none;">
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
        <textarea>{{profile.desc}}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery can simply toggle the elements and handle your ajax post.

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/your/url/"
    }).success(function(){
        $(".display, .edit").toggle();
        $("#descText").html($("textarea").val());
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zAtxp/1/)**

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution, I never though of toggle and it seems to be much better solution.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the js you have given, it is working fine on jsfiddle but when I run on development server the `$("#editButton").on("click", function()` is being fired twice as a result the whole thing toggles twice and the display remains the same. How I know this is happening is that I put an `alert()` call inside the function and the pop up came up twice.

Comment: When I remove the javasrcipt for the input button then the `$("#editButton")` js is being fired only once, but now the text area is not showing the text that it should. Although if I see the content of the textarea using alert then the text is there, but it is not being displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#editButton').click(function(){
  var text = $('descText').text();
  var textArea = $('<textarea></textarea>');
  textArea.value = text;
  $('#personalText').replaceWith(textArea);
});
```